# How to make an app that 2 cellphones can see the same data on android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to make an app that create "groups" between the people from your contacts who have the app and all the people in the group can see or update the same data.
Can ContentProviders do this or they only storage data for a single phone?
I just need you to tell me what to learn. And if you are feeling kind today, some links.
Thanks!

Comment: check out this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-2/

Comment: @Android Thanks, but should I need to use these Sockets even if my app is not a chat app? Only for display some information among groups of people.